# Parsing MySQL prepare statement

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to create a general insert/update function but I'm getting an error on the parsing statement.

First i create the Update and Insert string

```
$update = '$wpdb->prepare("UPDATE '. $dbTable. ' SET Distance = %d WHERE Date = %s AND UserID = %d", '. $distance. ', '. $today. ', '. $userID. ')';
$insert = '$wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO '. $dbTable. ' (Distance, Date, UserID) VALUES (%d,%s,%d)", '. $distance. ', '. $today. ', '. $userID. ')';
```

When I echo this it looks okay:

```
$wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO hfwp_Balance_Arm_Reach (Distance, Date, UserID) VALUES (%d,%s,%d)", 50, 2018-01-13, 29)
```

But when I pass it to my function I get a syntax error.

```
function hfwp_SaveFormData($update, $insert, $userID, $today, $dbTable)
{
  global $wpdb;
  $wpdb->show_errors();

  $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) UserID FROM $dbTable WHERE Date = %s AND UserID = %d", $today, $userID );
  $count = $wpdb->get_var($sql);

  if ($count > 0)
  {
    if (strpos($update, '$wpdb->prepare(' ) === 0) {

        $wpdb->query($update);

        if ($wpdb->last_error != "") {
            $error = $wpdb->last_error;
            hfwp_Log_Errors($update, $userID, $today, $error);
        }
    }

  }else{
    if (strpos($insert, '$wpdb->prepare(' ) === 0) {

        $wpdb->query($insert);

        if ($wpdb->last_error != "") {
            $error = $wpdb->last_error;
            hfwp_Log_Errors($insert, $userID, $today, $error);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Error:

```
<div id="error"><p class="wpdberror"><strong>WordPress databasefejl:</strong> [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 

&#039;$wpdb-&gt;prepare(&quot;INSERT INTO hfwp_Balance_Arm_Reach (Distance, Date, UserID) VALU&#039; at line 1]<br /><code>$wpdb-&gt;prepare(&quot;INSERT INTO hfwp_Balance_Arm_Reach (Distance, Date, UserID) VALUES (%d,%s,%d)&quot;, 50, 2018-01-13, 29)</code></p></div>

<div id="error"><p class="wpdberror"><strong>WordPress databasefejl:</strong> [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near &#039;$wpdb-&gt;prepare(&quot;INSERT INTO hfwp_Balance_Arm_Reach (Distance, Date, UserID) VALU&#039; at line 1]<br /><code></code></p></div>
```

Is it not possible to parse a SQL statement including the prepare "$wpdb->prepare" or am I missing something in my statement ???

Comment: `$update = '$wpdb->prepare("UPDATE '. $dbTable. ' SET Distance = %d WHERE Date = %s AND UserID = %d", '. $distance. ', '. $today. ', '. $userID. ')';
` seriously? The PHP code itself is being built as a string?!? Not simply the query?!?

Comment: Your right.
It's not cleaver. As suggestion below I properly need to do the prepare and parse the result of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `''` in update and insert

```
$update = $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE '. $dbTable. ' SET Distance = %d WHERE Date = %s AND UserID = %d, '. $distance. ', '. $today. ', '. $userID. '");
$insert =$wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO '. $dbTable. ' (Distance, Date, UserID) VALUES (%d,%s,%d)", '. $distance. ', '. $today. ', '. $userID.'");
```

and execute in funtion like this `$update->execute()`

you received syntx error because `$update` contains string not query
in your code here

`$wpdb->query($update);`

$update contains`'$wpdb->prepare("UPDATE '. $dbTable. ' SET Distance = %d WHERE Date = %s AND UserID = %d", '. $distance. ', '. $today. ', '. $userID. ')';` \

echen you print `$update` it will print the value of update which your prepare statement.

for e.g `$R='priot()';` do you think this will execute, it won't `$R` contain value i.e `priot()` not tha return value of `priot()`

learn [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)